# Bird identification - hawk

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

These fledglings are learning to fly in Salt Lake City, UT. What species are they?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please include an estimate of the size of these birds and if possible pictures of the adults that are likely to still be feeding them. To me these look like fledgling Red-tails, but the eye looks bluish rather than yellowish. However, that might be due to the lighting in your picture and this is a notoriously variable species. At any rate I think these are a buteo of some sort ...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your location and the unique coloration/arrangement of the feathers near the ear area, I would say these are [Northern Harrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_harrier) (*Circus hudsonius*) chicks.